# Creating an SQL view using UNION and a second SELECT

Tags: sql

I've got a table with records that have some properties. One of the properties is their state.

I also have a view that counts and groups the states. It looks like this:

```
State        Total

Canceled     9
Failed       3
Pending      10
Succeeded    7
```

Since there is no record with the 'Processing' state in my reference table, the view doesn't show it in the view. However, I want each of the five possible states in my view, even if it doesn't exist in the table.

I made the following query and am close to getting it to work (testing it with one of the available states):

```
SELECT State, COUNT(State) AS Total
FROM dbo.Job
GROUP BY State
UNION
SELECT 'Processing' AS State, 0 AS Total
```

The problem is my '0 AS Total'. The 0 should be dynamic. Is there a way I can replace it?

Comment: your DBMS is `SQL-Server`, isn't it?

Comment: and it seems you want to have `sum(total)` instead of `count(state)`, since your query gives the value 1 for count for all rows

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: Thanks for all replies! Since we didn't want to create a seperate table with states, Eric's answer worked best for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get a comprehensive list of `State`, all of the values have to come from somewhere other than your starting data set (assuming that not all values are represented, as is the current case with 'Processing'). That can be a table, which is your best option if you have the privileges to create such a table, or, if need be, from a list, which you'll then have to maintain if new `State` values are added.

In the second case, a table value constructor will do the job for you. Start with that constructor, then `LEFT JOIN` to your data source. An `INNER JOIN` will, again, filter off values missing in your underlying data.

```
SELECT
  s.[State]
 ,COUNT(j.[State]) AS Total
FROM
    (
      VALUES
        ('Canceled')
       ,('Failed')
       ,('Pending')
       ,('Succeeded')
       ,('Processing')
    ) AS s ([State])
  LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.Job AS j
      ON
      s.[State] = j.[State]
GROUP BY
  s.[State];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `LEFT JOIN` to dictionary table that contains all possible states:

```
SELECT s.State, COUNT(j.State) AS Total
FROM StateTable s
LEFT JOIN dbo.Job j
  ON s.state = j.state
GROUP BY s.State
```

Answer (score 0):

Either make a table with all states and join it in or hard code a list of states in your script (but this is probably a bad way to do it).

Answer (score 0):

You could add an extra grouping around your original query:

`SELECT State, SUM(Total)
FROM (
  SELECT State, COUNT(State) AS Total
  FROM dbo.Job
  GROUP BY State
  UNION
  SELECT 'Processing' AS State, 0 AS Total)
GROUP BY State`

If there are any 'Processing' entries in your dbo.Job table, they will be added to the 0 from the Union.

The other option is as Matt D suggested: create a reference table with all possible states in it and then LEFT OUTER JOIN the dbo.Job table to it.

```
SELECT s.State, COUNT(j.State) AS Total
FROM dbo.All_States s
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Job j
ON s.State = j.State
GROUP BY s.State
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `rollup` :

```
SELECT coalesce(state,'Processing') as State, sum(Total) as Total
  FROM dbo.Job
 GROUP BY rollup(State);
```

[***`Rextester Demo`***](http://rextester.com/JEPU12621)